# Can i make the android app load only specific pages of a pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am making an educational app and I am using a few books as material for learning. It's pharmacology books for USMLE and NAPLEX students.  The pdfs are around 600 pages. Let's say the user opens lesson 3 which is from 23 to 31. The way the app is now is that the user opens page 23 and switches the pages but he can see pages over 31. Is there a way to make the pdf file appear as if 31 is the last page?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a library I think you can use : https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

It has custom page loading functions like, 
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
    .pages(yourcustompages from 23 to 31) // all pages are displayed by default
    .defaultPage(23)